# typed/racket: Declare struct in unit signature

Tags: racket, typed-racket

Given I have Racket typed module

```
(require typed/racket/unit
         Engine/engine2-sig)

(define-unit engine2@
  (import)
  (export engine2-sig^)

  (define-struct posn ([x : Natural] [y : Natural] [z : Natural])
    #:transparent)
  )

(provide engine2@)
```

with following signature

```
#lang typed/racket

(require typed/racket/unit)

(define-signature engine2-sig^
  ([posn : ???]))

(provide engine2-sig^)
```

What should I put instead of question marks to export struct called `posn`?

I cannot find appropriate example in docs [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/Typed_Units.html), am I missing something?